# Chaincode instantiation failed in Hyperledger Fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

**Problem:**

I have created a Hyperledger fabric network and a custom chaincode for my network. After running the network I install the chaincode on my network. It was successful for all peers. But when I try to instantiate the chaincode it gives me this error on the cli.

> Error: could not assemble transaction, err proposal response was not
>   successful, error code 500, msg chaincode registration failed:
>   container exited  with 1

But all other chaincode including fabcar and one chaincode which I was wrote was instantiated successfully. But only this chaincode was failed.

This is my package.json of that chaincode.

```
{
  "name": "helthcare",
  "version": "1.3.0",
  "description": "Chain code for HRM",
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=8.4.0",
    "npm": ">=6.4.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node helthcare.js"
  },
  "engine-strict": true,
  "author": "Janith Shanilka",
  "license": "Apache-2.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "fabric-shim": "~1.4.0"
  }
}
```

This is my chaincode.

```
"use strict";
const shim = require("fabric-shim");
const util = require("util");

let Chaincode = class {
  async Init(stub) {
    //this method is to Initialized the chincode on the channel
    console.info("=========== Instantiated HRM chaincode ===========");
    return shim.success();
  }

  async Invoke(stub) {
    let ret = stub.getFunctionAndParameters();
    console.info(ret);

    let method = this[ret.fcn];
    if (!method) {
      console.error("no function of name:" + ret.fcn + " found");
      throw new Error("Received unknown function " + ret.fcn + " invocation");
    }
    try {
      let payload = await method(stub, ret.params);
      return shim.success(payload);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
      return shim.error(err);
    }
  }


  async patientRegistration(stub, args) {
    console.info("============= START : Registering a Patient ===========");
    if (args.length != 22) {
      throw new Error(
        `Incorrect number of arguments. Expecting 22 got ${args.length}`
      );
    }

    let patientAsBytes = await stub.getState(args[0]); //get the particular patient from the ledger
    //console.log("hiiiii" + driverAsBytes.toString());
    if (patientAsBytes.toString()) {
      //check weather he is already registered or not
      console.log(patientAsBytes.toString());
      throw new Error("patient with ID" + args[0] + " Already registered");
    }

    var patient = {
      docType: "patient",
      title: args[0],
      firstName: args[1],
      middlename: args[2],
      surname: args[3],
      dob: args[4],
      sex: args[5],
      bloodtype: args[6],
      height: [7],
      weight: [8],
      allergy: [9],
      addressline1: args[10],
      addressline2: args[11],
      city: args[12],
      postalcode: args[13],
      email: args[14],
      contactno: args[15],
      etitle: args[16],
      efirstName: args[17],
      esurname: args[18],
      contactno1: args[19],
      contactno2: args[20],
      erelationship: args[21]
    };

    await stub.putState(patient.email, Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(patient))); //add new patient to ledger
    console.info("============= END : Registering a patient ===========");
  }

  async addDoctor(stub, args) {
    console.info("============= START : Registering a doctor ===========");
    if (args.length != 12) {
      throw new Error(
        `Incorrect number of arguments. Expecting 12 got ${args.length}`
      );
    }

    let doctorAsBytes = await stub.getState(args[0]); //get the particular doctor from ledger
    if (doctorAsBytes.toString()) {
      console.log(doctorAsBytes.toString());
      //check weather he is already registered or not
      throw new Error("doctor with RegNo" + args[0] + " Already registered");
    }

    var doctor = {
      docType: "doctor",
      title: args[0],
      firstName: args[1],
      surname: args[2],
      medicalregno: args[3],
      dob: args[4],
      sex: args[5],
      speciality: args[6],
      addressline1: args[7],
      addressline2: args[8],
      city: args[8],
      postalcode: args[9],
      email: args[10],
      contactno: args[11],
    };

    await stub.putState(doctor.email, Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(doctor))); //add new doctor to the ledger
    console.info("============= END : Registering a doctor ===========");
  }


  async makeDiagnosis(stub, args) {
    console.info("============ START : Make a Diagnosis ==========");
    if (args.length != 6) {
      throw new Error(
        `Incorrect number of arguments. Expecting 6 got ${args.length}`
      );
    }

    var diagnosis = {
      docType: "diagnosis",
      id: args[0],
      patientid : args[1],
      doctorid : args[2],
      sysdate : args[3],
      systime : args[4],
      diagnosis: args[5]
    };

    await stub.putState(diagnosis.id, Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(diagnosis))); //put the new fine into leadger

    console.info("============ END: Make a Diagnosis ==========");
  }


  async selectNthDoctor(stub, args) {
    console.info("============= START : Selecting a doctor ===========");
    if (args.length != 1) {
      throw new Error(
        "Incorrect number of arguments. Expecting regNo ex: doctorhrm@gmail.com"
      );
    }
    let email = args[0];

    let doctorAsBytes = await stub.getState(email); //get the officer from state
    if (!doctorAsBytes.toString() || doctorAsBytes.toString().length <= 0) {
      throw new Error("Officer with Email" + email + " does not exist");
    }
    console.log(doctorAsBytes.toString());
    console.info("============= END : Selecting a doctor ===========");
    return doctorAsBytes;
  }

  async selectNthPatient(stub, args) {
    console.info("============= START : Selecting a patient ===========");
    if (args.length != 1) {
      throw new Error(
        "Incorrect number of arguments. Expecting patient Id ex: patienthrm@gmail.com"
      );
    }
    let email = args[0];

    let patientAsBytes = await stub.getState(email); //get the offence from ledger
    if (!patientAsBytes.toString() || patientAsBytes.toString().length <= 0) {
      throw new Error("Offence with Email" + email + " does not exist");
    }
    console.log(patientAsBytes.toString());
    console.info("============= END : Selecting a doctor ===========");
    return patientAsBytes;
  }


  async selectNthDiagnosis(stub, args) {
    console.info("============= START : Selecting a diagnosis ===========");
    if (args.length != 1) {
      throw new Error("Incorrect number of arguments. Expecting ID ex: D001");
    }
    let dId = args[0];

    let diagnosisAsBytes = await stub.getState(dId); //select payment from ledger
    if (!diagnosisAsBytes.toString() || diagnosisAsBytes.toString().length <= 0) {
      throw new Error("Payment with dId" + dId + " does not exist");
    }
    console.log(diagnosisAsBytes.toString());
    console.info("============= END : Selecting a diagnosis ===========");
    return diagnosisAsBytes;
  }

  async nthDocotorDiagnosis(stub, args) {
    console.info("============= START : Mango Query Slecting all diagonsis of Doctors ===========");
    if (args.length != 1) {
      throw new Error(
        "Incorrect number of arguments. Expecting Email ex: doctorhrm@gmail.com"
      );
    }

    let email = args[0];

    let query = {
      "selector": {
        "docType": "diagnosis",
        "doctorid": email
      }
    };

    let diagnosisAsBytes = await stub.getQueryResult(JSON.stringify(query));

    console.log(diagnosisAsBytes.toString());
    console.info("============= END : Mango Query Slecting all diagonsis of Doctors ===========");
    return diagnosisAsBytes;

  }

  async nthPatientDiagnosis(stub, args) {
    console.info("============= START : Mango Query Slecting all diagonsis of Patient ===========");
    if (args.length != 1) {
      throw new Error(
        "Incorrect number of arguments. Expecting email ex: patienthrm@gmail.com"
      );
    }

    let email = args[0];

    let diagnosisAsBytes = await stub.getQueryResult({
      selector: {
        docType: "diagnosis",
        patientid: email
      }
    });

    console.log(diagnosisAsBytes.toString());
    console.info("============= END : Mango Query Slecting all diagonsis of Doctors ===========");
    return diagnosisAsBytes;
  }

  async getAllDoctors(stub, args) {
    let queryString = {};
    queryString.selector = {};
    queryString.selector.docType = "doctor";
    let resultsIterator = await stub.getQueryResult(
      JSON.stringify(queryString)
    );
    let allResults = [];
    while (true) {
      let res = await resultsIterator.next();

      if (res.value && res.value.value.toString()) {
        let jsonRes = {};
        console.log(res.value.value.toString("utf8"));
        jsonRes.Key = res.value.key;
        try {
          jsonRes.Record = JSON.parse(res.value.value.toString("utf8"));
        } catch (err) {
          console.log(err);
          jsonRes.Record = res.value.value.toString("utf8");
        }

        allResults.push(jsonRes);
      }
      if (res.done) {
        await resultsIterator.close();
        let queryResults = Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(allResults));
        console.log(queryResults.toString());
        return queryResults;
      }
    }
  }

  async getAllPatient(stub, args) {
    let queryString = {};
    queryString.selector = {};
    queryString.selector.docType = "patient";
    let resultsIterator = await stub.getQueryResult(
      JSON.stringify(queryString)
    );
    let allResults = [];
    while (true) {
      let res = await resultsIterator.next();

      if (res.value && res.value.value.toString()) {
        let jsonRes = {};
        console.log(res.value.value.toString("utf8"));
        jsonRes.Key = res.value.key;
        try {
          jsonRes.Record = JSON.parse(res.value.value.toString("utf8"));
        } catch (err) {
          console.log(err);
          jsonRes.Record = res.value.value.toString("utf8");
        }

        allResults.push(jsonRes);
      }
      if (res.done) {
        await resultsIterator.close();
        let queryResults = Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(allResults));
        console.log(queryResults.toString());
        return queryResults;
      }
    }
  }

  async getAllDiagnosis(stub, args) {
    let queryString = {};
    queryString.selector = {};
    queryString.selector.docType = "diagnosis";
    let resultsIterator = await stub.getQueryResult(
      JSON.stringify(queryString)
    );
    let allResults = [];
    while (true) {
      let res = await resultsIterator.next();

      if (res.value && res.value.value.toString()) {
        let jsonRes = {};
        console.log(res.value.value.toString("utf8"));
        jsonRes.Key = res.value.key;
        try {
          jsonRes.Record = JSON.parse(res.value.value.toString("utf8"));
        } catch (err) {
          console.log(err);
          jsonRes.Record = res.value.value.toString("utf8");
        }

        allResults.push(jsonRes);
      }
      if (res.done) {
        await resultsIterator.close();
        let queryResults = Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(allResults));
        console.log(queryResults.toString());
        return queryResults;
      }
    }
  }

};

shim.start(new Chaincode());
```

Can someone help me to solve this problem? I tried a lot to find out a solution to this problem. But I was unable to find a solution to this problem.Thank you.

Comment: Check the logs of your chaincode. Do `docker ps` followed by `docker logs dev-peer0-something-xxxx`. This will point you to the exact error in your deployment. Without the logs it is difficult to figure out the mistake.

Comment: @VarunAgarwal It is not creating that is the issue. But with fabcar chaincode, it is creating dev-peer0

Comment: ok so I have faced this kind of issues. You got to debug the correct way. Chaincode containers ALWAYS start. After that either they stop and remain as images or they get deleted entirely. You can do `docker image ls` so check if it is an image and get logs. This usually happens if there is an issue in the code. If the container is deleted you got to keep doing `docker ps` while it is instantiating and quickly catch the logs before it deletes itself. Not ideal but it is how I debug if needed.

Comment: Can you please share the logs of the chaincode container.